# On Conflict Do Nothing in Postgres with a not-null constraint

Tags: postgresql

Is it not possible to utilize "ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING" to avoid inserting and violating a not-null constraint?

For example...

```
INSERT INTO public.users (user, user_yob, sex) 
SELECT mom, mom_yob, 'F' 
FROM staging.users 
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Produces this error and stops...

```
INSERT INTO public.users (user, user_yob, sex) SELECT mom, mom_yob, 'F' FROM staging.users ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
> ERROR:  null value in column "user" violates not-null constraint
  DETAIL:  Failing row contains (0b159b81-6842-4ae7-961c-2e9cff8488b1, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, F).
```

Ideally, this particular insert would be ignored rather than raise the error.

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/292428/postgresql-upsert-issue-with-not-null-columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) says:

> The optional `ON CONFLICT` clause specifies an alternative action to raising a **unique violation** or **exclusion constraint violation** error.

`NOT NULL` is neither a unique nor an exclusion constraint. Technically speaking, it is not even a proper constraint in PostgreSQL.

What you need is a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that returns `NULL` if the `NEW` row contains offending null values.

Comment: Thank you and that makes sense... I read the docs but didn't realize that "not-null" is not technically a constraint. Is there a better way to do this than just setting "NOT NULL" on a column?

Comment: No; what's wrong with `NOT NULL`? Did you investigate the option of using a trigger?

Comment: I just making sure I wasn't missing something else. I'm doing the trigger now and it does the trick. I'll accept your answer.