# Ignore individual nulls when upserting into non-null columns with coalesce

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I'd like to construct a partial insert-on-conflict-update statement that can take null values for non-null columns, as long as the updated row has the value so that the constraint wouldn't be violated. And in the case of multiple columns, I'd like each to be updated even if one is null and then ignored.

When updating values using `coalesce(excluded.value, table.value)`, I’d expect the statement to accept a null, because the existing value will be used, satisfying the constraint. However, the statement ends up in error saying that the non-null constraint was violated.

To test it, here's a MWE:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT NOT NULL, val INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));
INSERT INTO test VALUES (0, 1);

INSERT INTO test
VALUES (0, 2)
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO UPDATE SET val=COALESCE(EXCLUDED.val, test.val);
SELECT * FROM test;

INSERT INTO test
VALUES (0, null)
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO UPDATE SET val=COALESCE(EXCLUDED.val, test.val);
SELECT * FROM test;
```

And here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8d9c1/6) to do the same.

So I take it that the constraint is checked already in `VALUES`, not in `SET`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48816629/4616087) seems to suggest that you need to use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. I'm not an expert on postgresql, though.

Comment: @Marvin I'd like the update to run, to update other columns even though one might be null (also updated the question to reflect that, thanks). Or maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: I understand why you say you expect the statement to accept null but you really should not. It is a query that tries to insert `null` on a `NOT NULL` column after all... The DB does, in order: 1. check the constraint on the record being inserted (your latter query fails **here**), 2. check the conflict, 3. insert the record if there is no conflict or update the existing record if there is.

Comment: Constraints(NOT NULL) are checked first so this is not going to work.  As stated above you will need a BEFORE INSERT trigger.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I haven't used them before, so I'd gladly accept an answer showing how! But in any case, thank you, I'll try to look for information.

Comment: Good place to start [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you very well.You will never be able to insert a null into a non-null, but if you want to check to return another value then you could use the COALESCE function directly on insert.

To do an insert you could always check it in the insert:

```
INSERT INTO test
VALUES (1, COALESCE(null, 2));
select * from test;
```

And CONFLICT for when it is an insert of a primary key or unique that already exists:

```
INSERT INTO test
VALUES (0, 1)
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO UPDATE SET val=COALESCE(EXCLUDED.val, test.val);
select * from test;

INSERT INTO test (id, val)
VALUES (0, 1)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET id=test.id+1, val=test.val;
select * from test;
```

And here's an [SQL Fiffle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8d9c1/85)

Otherwise you will have to update it using a trigger, because as @Atmo explained to you the DB does, in order:

1. check the constraint on the record being inserted (your latter query fails here)
2. check the conflict
3. insert the record if there is no conflict or update the existing record if there is.