# Updating the column of object in rails object by its position in the array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an array of objects in Rails for some table. I want to update its order field by the position of that object in the array with a single Active Record Query. How can I do that?

I have tried the `update_all.(:"order" => ?)` but couldn't get the object which is updating in `update_all`.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose @user (only a reference you can use your corresponding object) is the array of objects **(Activerecord)** , then to update order field of all users in the array, you would have to run the following query

```
@user.update_all(order_field: value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an array of `posts`, then you can do something like the following

```
posts.each_with_index do |post, index| 
  post.update_attributes order: index 
end
```

This will execute a single query for each `post`. If you want a single query to update all the posts in the array, that is a lot harder to achieve. Options I can think of:

- bulk updating
- using a stored procedure

Comment: its correct but , I am trying to do it in a single query is it possible...??

Comment: It is possible, but a lot more complicated and not sure it is worth it imho. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563869/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-a-single-sql-query